# Have astronauts seen asteroids or comets?

Tags: astronauts, observation

Have astronauts ever seen asteroids or comets from space, either by eye, through a camera, or a telescope?

Comment: Is this question mainly focuses on _scientist on Earth_ or _astronaut in spacecraft (e.g. ISS)_? Both perspectives would result differently.

Comment: "Scientist on Earth" observes asteroids/comets "from space". Make sense eh? Just to make sure you're referring to "astronaut". Chill geez ;)

Comment: @Boosted - what uhoh is trying to get you to see is that the question makes it very explicit that it is the view from space. Not sure how this could be misunderstood.

Comment: @uhoh I'm cool and I got it. It's unnecessary to extend the issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

> The crew of the International Space Station enjoyed a front seat view
>   of the Lovejoy Comet as they flew over the Southern Hemisphere. The
>   Expedition 30 crew captured video footage of the comet from aboard the
>   space station as part of Crew Earth Observations. Astronaut Dan
>   Burbank described the sight as, "the most amazing thing I have ever
>   seen in space."

[image]

[reference](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/news/Comet_Lovejoy.html) (December 2011)

Comet ISON

[image]

[Reference](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/516/ison-from-the-iss/?category=small-bodies_comets) (December 2013)

The severely over-hyped Comet Kohoutek was observed from Skylab. This is a sketch from visual observation made by one of the crew.

[image]

[Reference](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-404/ch4.htm) (December 1973)

*December seems to be the month for observing comets from space stations*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIgUvj4aDc8

Comment: I think the first pic in the answer is a still from that video.

Comment: The Skylab data link is super interesting, and hand-drawn notes of visual observation is a great find! fyi I've just asked [How did Skylab's electrographic camera work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32497/12102)

Comment: Skylab gets overlooked a lot, but it was pretty amazing.

Comment: Here's Terry Lovejoy's tweet about the comet that may be visible in next week or two https://twitter.com/TerryLovejoy66/status/1067914174338985985 Sky and Telescope: https://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/comet-46p-wirtanen-approaches-earth/ just fyi

Answer (score 7):

And now meteoroid (i.e. burning asteoroid):

GIF:

[image: bright meteoroid seen from ISS]

(taken from [ESA video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNixNC_mAk8))

Comment: That's beautiful and makes a very nice addition, thank you! I added a "GIF" label since some users may have GIFs disabled by default in their browser (to avoid advertising).