# At what wavelengths and for what particle types have astronomical objects been imaged or at least directionally resolved from the ISS?

Tags: iss, space-telescope, astronomy, radio-telescope, nicer

The ISS has an X-ray telescope called NICER and [this answer in Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36080/7982) (and links therein) explain that it was able to show that there are hot spots clustered near one pole of the pulsar PSR J0030+0451.

There have been several mentions of a telescope inside the ISS that people can point out a window, but I don't think this can be used practically for astronomical observations.

Skylab had an ultraviolet telescope which produced a great deal of new observations at wavelengths only observable from space. [How did Skylab's electrographic ultraviolet camera work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32497/12102)

Besides NICER at X-ray, at what electromagnetic wavelengths have astronomical observations been made from the ISS, and what kinds of particles *besides photons* have been imaged or directionally resolved?

Comment: companion question: [At what wavelengths and for what particle types have astronomical objects been imaged or at least directionally resolved from Tiangong stations?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43931/12102)

Comment: You might consider the AMS, NICER's next door neighbor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer

Comment: @JohnDoty nobody has posted an answer yet...

Comment: Since link-only answers are anathema here, I have nothing to add. I am not an expert on AMS.

Comment: different but related: [Has radio astronomy ever been done from a space station or crewed capsule?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54696/12102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not claiming to be exhaustive, but there are/were:

- [MAXI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAXI_(ISS_experiment)), is a soft X-ray all-sky monitor (0.7-20 keV)
- [AMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer), is a cosmic ray detector
- [CALET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimetric_Electron_Telescope), is again a cosmic ray detector working in synergy with AMS
- [SOLAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLAR_(ISS)), was studying the Sun's spectral irradiance from UV to IR (17nm-100µm)
- [DOSTEL](https://www.swsc-journal.org/articles/swsc/abs/2015/01/swsc150028/swsc150028.html), was another cosmic ray detector/dosimeter, to measure the radiation exposure inside and outside the ISS.

Comment: I've just added a bounty on the [companion question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43931/12102)